# Drag and Drop between 2 tables using Jquery sortable with rowspan and colspan

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I`m trying to move a row that has rowspan > 2 or colspan > 2 in another table.

The problem is that when I drop it into a cell , it creates a new tr in that cell.

I`m thinking to set the parent rowspan or colspan same as child when the dragged object is dropped.

http://jsbin.com/jumalofe/1/watch?html,js,output

Let`s say that "AIBD" should be from 08-00 to 12:00 . How should I do that??

Comment: Do you need it to be `<td>AIBD</td>` instead of `<td><tr><td>AIBD</td></tr></td>`?

Comment: I want to be able to put more in the same table cell. In the end it should be like: http://www.fsc.ugal.ro/nou/files/studenti/orare/an_4_C.pdf

Comment: In the jsbin demo you have provided, I can put _AIBD_ and _SINCO_ in the same cell. Sorry, I don't understand your issue.

Comment: It`s ok. I`ll be more specific. AIBD has colspan 2 in the first table. When i move it in the second table it will be: <td><tr><td colspan="2">AIBD</td></tr></td> and i want <td colspan="2"><tr><td>....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you do. We will use the `receive` event of sortable:

> **receive( event, ui )**
>
> This event is triggered when an item from a connected sortable list
>   has been dropped into another list. The latter is the event target.

```
receive:function(event, ui) {

      //we check if the <td> has rowspan property
     if(typeof ui.item.attr('rowspan') !== 'undefined' && ui.item.attr('rowspan') !== false){

        //if it does, we store it in a variable
        rowspan = ui.item.attr('rowspan');

        //the element we are dropping to, we set the rowspan there
        //(content is automatically inserted)
        $(this).attr('rowspan',rowspan);

        //we set the rowspan of sender element to 0, this is the case where
        //you are re-dragging the 'AIDB' to some other row, if you do, 
        //we want the previous row to be same as before, free of any rowspan
        ui.sender.attr('rowspan',0);

      }

      //same case for colspan
      if(typeof ui.item.attr('colspan') !== 'undefined' && ui.item.attr('colspan') !== false){

        colspan = ui.item.attr('colspan');
        $(this).attr('colspan',colspan);
        ui.sender.attr('colspan',0);

      }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/toyugodu/1/edit?js,output)**

Comment: Thank you! With rowspan it works, but creates a new cell at the end of the next row. With colspan it doesn`t work. Unfortunely, i`m a newbie in js and i don`t know what can be wrong.

Comment: @CristianSimion I've fixed it to work with colspan but the new cell thing is complicated. The idea is, if suppose you have a colspan of 2, the last cell which is coming out will be removed, but if you are going to drop the cell at the last element, then that won't work.